# Insert newline between the items of dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, drop-down-menu

I want give some space between the items of the dropdownlist. is it possible?

ex:

ddl:

```
    item1

    item2

    item3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean a `<select>`, no this isn't possible, at least not in a cross-browser way (unless you add empty, selectable `<option>` elements, which I wouldn't guess that you want in there.

To do this you need to use something that replaces the `<select>` with stylable elements, here are some options:

- [Stylish Select Box](http://www.prismstudio.co.uk/2009/05/jquery-plugin-stylish-select-unobstrusive-select-box-replacement/)
- [Select Box Replacement](http://www.templates-scripts.com/2010/02/jquery-select-box-replacement/)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
        comboBox1.Items.Add("item1");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("item2");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("item3");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS.

example:

```
select option
{
    line-height: 35px;

}
```

Comment: You can't style a `<select>` cross-browser.  `option` just shouldn't appear in your stylesheet unless it's for fonts.